# Saving JPEG from PDF using Adobe Acrobat Pro Javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I am attempting to save a *.jpeg file from a PDF using JavaScript and Adobe Acrobat Pro.

However, when I try to save the JPEG file, I consistently encounter an error message indicating that there may be insufficient hard drive space, and as a result, the file fails to save.

Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
// Überprüfen, ob das Dateiformat PDF ist
if (app.viewerType !== "Reader" && this.path.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf")) {

  // Anzahl der Datumsfelder
  var numOfDateFields = 13;

  // Standardordner für den Druck, wenn alle Datumsfelder belegt sind
  var printFolder = "C:\\Temp\\";

  // Flag, um zu überprüfen, ob ein leeres Datumsfeld gefunden wurde
  var emptyDateFieldFound = false;

  // Schleife durch die Datumsfelder
  for (var i = 1; i <= numOfDateFields; i++) {
    var dateFieldName = "Datum" + i;

    // Überprüfen, ob das Datumsfeld leer ist
    if (this.getField(dateFieldName).value === "") {
      // Leeres Datumsfeld gefunden, setzen Sie das aktuelle Datum
      this.getField(dateFieldName).value = util.printd("dd.mm.yyyy", new Date());
      emptyDateFieldFound = true;
      break; // Stoppen Sie die Schleife, wenn ein leeres Datumsfeld gefunden wurde
    }
  }

  // Wenn kein leeres Datumsfeld gefunden wurde und es das letzte Datumsfeld ist
  if (!emptyDateFieldFound && i > numOfDateFields) {
      // PDF-Datei drucken, wenn alle Datumsfelder belegt sind

  // Erstellen Sie einen Zeitstempel für den Dateinamen
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var timestamp = currentDate.getTime();

  // Datei mit Zeitstempel erstellen
  this.saveAs({
      cPath: "/c/Temp/Test_" + timestamp + ".jpg",
      cConvID: "com.adobe.acrobat.jpeg"
  });

  this.resetForm();
  }
}
```

I attempted to utilize a trusted function, but unfortunately, this approach also proved unsuccessful.

Comment: Hi K J,

Thank you for your prompt response. I'm a bit unclear on your previous answer, so I'll provide more context on what I'm trying to accomplish:

The file comprises a table with 13 rows.
Each row contains a field for the date.
Whenever the file is opened, the next available date field should be automatically populated with today's date.
Once all the rows are filled, the file should be saved as a JPEG, and the form should be cleared, allowing for a fresh start with the same file.

Comment: The problem I was not able to solve is, when I save the PDF file itself, teh saved PDF file is the one that is open and my originale file is not. This document shall be accessed via QR-Code and thats why its necessary to have a static file name. The saved jpeg is for archive purposes.

Comment: I do understand, thank you. That means there will be no solution the way I was trying?!
Do you see a different approach?

Comment: I give you al little bit more context on whats the purpose of this document:
This document is needed once every working day, since into this document a calibration test gets documentet. The document shall be accessed via an iPad and the file itself is somewhere on our fileserver. With the QR Code we are able to open the document via apples documents. Basically this document shall only gets opened by the iPad and it shall archive and clear up itself automatically.